# How to measure hash algorithm strength

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

Is there a way to measure the strength of hash algorithms? For instance, a standardised test, written in PHP, to measure the strength of, perhaps, `crypt` vs. `sha1`?

Strength can refer to various things; the ability a single home computer can discover the password through a rainbow table or a character loop, the length of bits in the password or the use of symbols and numbers. Unlike simple regular expressions which discover symbols or the number of characters, a requirement for the PHP function which can determine strength, is from how fast the password, key or salt can be broken.

I would like to know, without opinion, which hashing algorithm is best from a PHP's list of hashing algorithms.

```
foreach (hash_algos() as $algorithm) {
    // test strength
}
```

Comment: What does "strength" of hash means exactly to you? It has several meanings? And why is it so important to you exactly? What do you use it for?

Comment: Finding weaknesses in state-of-the-art hashing algorithms is research-level cryptography. If there was an algorithm for it, quite a few clever people would be without job (or at least spend their time differently).

Comment: You'd be better off googling for comparisons - lots of people have written articles on each type and the benefits etc.

Comment: well usually strength of hash is measurting due to its bitsize. LIke sha-2 . which means 2^64 - 1 of possible uncolliding hash codes

Comment: @safarov I can come up with hash algorithms that result in 65,536-bit integers which nonetheless is so weak some undergraduates could beat it.

Comment: If there was a "best" one, it wouldn't be a secret (at least after it was de-classified).  If it's available via `hash_algos` that means it either used to be good, is pretty good for somethings, or it's pretty darn good, given that it's free and publicly available.  Every hashing algorithm has collision, because of the pigeonhole principle (or as I like to call it, "Why you can't have a 2-in-1 shampoo"), and some have been broken faster than others.  At the end of the day, whatever you're securing is more secure offline and probably not so valuable (no offense) that you need "the best".

Comment: @delnan 65,536 is nothing , we talking about 2^64 and 2^128 bit

Comment: @safarov: I don't think there are many length-2^128 hash algorithms out there...

Comment: @safarov Don't confuse bit count with the number range. A 128-bit integer requires 16 byte to store and permits 2^128 values, which is quite a bit and sensible for a hashign algorithm. A 2^128 bit integer would require 10^25 terabyte to store and permits 2^(2^128) values (this number has 10^38 decimal digits) - IOW, freakin' impractical. But in any case, my point was: The output number range has very little to do with the strength (by any reasonable definition of strength) of the algorithm. [All numbers brought to you by Wolfram|Alpha]

Comment: @delnan thanks for detail, will study more about this

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to write a function that tests the strength of an arbitrary hash function. But it'll take a while to run. ;)

Comment: While this similar question *isnt* asking about cryptographic strength, answers show examples of measuring hash distribution - stackoverflow.com/questions/24729730

Answer (score 5):

The strength of a hash is a mathematical/theoretical concept, i.e. if any theoretical or practical differences have been found.

If there are no published weaknesses then the strength is the length of the digest. E.g. SHA-1 has a 160 bit output, but SHA-256 has a 256 bit output.

The only way to "programatically" test the strength would be to brute force the hash which is mostly pointless.

It would be better to research each of the hashes yourself instead of trying to programatically determine the 'best' one.

Answer (score 1):

A hashing algorithm maps an arbitrary input to an output sequence of `n` bits.  A "good" hashing algorithm maps every input of length `n` bits to a *different* output sequence of `n` bits.  A *collision* occurs when two *different* inputs map to the *same* output.

So a simple way to test the comparative strength of two hashing algorithms would be to generate a large set of inputs, feed them to both algorithms, and count the number of collisions.

Note that "simple" means "conceptually simple."  Performing the actual test will require a significant amount of computing resources.

Comment: Collision must occur, as there is a finite number of bits and an infinite number of sequences that can be hashed. Not that you didn't know that, but thought your answer was a good spot to point that out.

Comment: The best hash will map an input of `n` bits to an output of `n` bits without collision.  Collisions must occur only if the length of the input is greater than the length of the output.

Comment: @AdamLiss: I don't think this is really the important criterion.  A more important measure is how easy it is to construct an input that results in a given output.

Comment: @AdamLiss: Not at all.  I'm sure MD5 obeys the property you're describing, but the reason MD5 is now considered insecure is that it is "relatively" easy to maliciously create an input that produces a collision.

Answer (score 0):

I think mathematically, a good way to look at it would be to consider the running time of an algorithm to compute the key given the other appropriate inputs, if such an algorithm exists.

Based on some of my recent tooling around with some basic cryptographic algorithms, I can say that the fastest algorithm to find k for even a basic exponential cipher runs in e^(sqrt(log p log log p) making it infeasible for large p. It seems like this would be a good theoretical measurement of "strength."

I am by no means an expert on such things, Gavin and Adam seem to be much more knowledgeable.